# DPDT Switch Microcontroller

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, circuit-analysis, switches, circuit-design

Is there a microcontroller equivalent of a DPDT Switch? I am trying to develop a product that requires remote reversal of polarity by incorporation some sort of an equivalent of the mechanism exhibited by a DPDT switch.

Comment: polarity of what voltage and which currents? What is attached to that? Maybe you've heard of an **H-Bridge**, but with the little info you're giving us here, we can't tell you whether that is appropriate.

Comment: Start with this datasheet https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/DRV8837DSGR/296-34806-1-ND/3518833  much to learn.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. A very simple polarity reversal circuit using two GPIOs. [GPIO tricks](http://lednique.com/gpio-tricks/2-gpio-1-bi-colour-2-pin-led/).*

```
GPIO1 GPIO2  LED
----- -----  -----
  0     0    Off
  1     0    Green
  0     1    Red
  1     1    Off
```